# Gmail markup (google-schema) rejected

Tags: google-schemas

We have added google-schema markup to our transaction emails (we send around 10k emails daily using mandrill) and tested them by sending from/to same email address, email markup tester and all tools available with google.

When we send them to google whitelisting for approval we get a mail with below reply even though we are good on all 4 points below (my answers in bracket)

1. Email’s domain not authenticated properly (DKIM, SPF). **(done, DKIM and SPF is valid as per Mandrill, our email header says signed by NOBroker.in)**
2. Authenticated domain does not match the “From:” email’s domain. **(it does)**
3. Not enough volume sent to Gmail addresses (need more than 100 emails/day). **(We send 10k transactional emails a day)**
4. Spam reputation is too low (too many spam complaints from users/emails qualified as spam).**(our reputation is excellent with negligible spam reports)**

I sent a email on top of this mail asking for more details but didn't got much info except few more generic steps to check.

I am looking for help with this if someone from google can check internally on the reason for rejection or someone on this forum who has also faced this issue in past and was able resolve it later

Any help would be highly appreciated and if you happen to be in Bangalore, coffee is due on me :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Google cannot provide all the information on why your request got rejected. There is a review team who checks for all the points mentioned in the email. Its not that they might have missed something that you are rejected even though if you think you are good in all the points mentioned in the website. There might be problem with the volume or the spam reputation which you are not making sure on. Please try to build some good spam reputation and try requesting again after fews days as mentioned in the email from the Google team.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Our Spam reputation is excellent and volume is much higher than what gmail asks for. I really need specific pointers to solve the issue, else it becomes more of shooting in dark.